# Too ill to fly, visa ending, Cruise line also refusing - what can I do?

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, health, children, sea-travel

I'm an American citizen living in the UK. My 7 month old son was born with a collapsed lung and sustained an injury to his lung as a result. He's been given clearance to travel by boat but not to fly as flying could prove deadly.

I'm on a visa currently. Moving back to the States in March but have been denied by cruise line for him to travel due to his age and lung issue. He is not cleared to fly by plane either. WHAT CAN I DO? It's not an option to extend my visa. I'm more than willing to wait until he's of age to travel by boat which is 12 months but as I said, they said they won't take him. 
Can I ask the US embassy to help me?

Comment: You say that it's not an option to extend your visa - have you spoken with UK immigration authorities - there are exceptions for medical emergencies etc?

Comment: I don't want to stay in UK any longer as my mother is sick with cancer in the USA and need to get back to care for her. I emailed the embassy this morning. Waiting for reply.

Comment: so you don't want to stay due to other circumstances. That's not the same as it not being possible to get a visa extension (although it does mean that you probably shouldn't bother)

Comment: I'm fairly well convinced this is not the place to come for an answer to this problem. You are, almost literally) between a rock and a hard place. You'll need to communicate with the proper authorities regarding the help you require. Best of Luck to you, your child, and your mother.

Comment: Which cruise line? Cunard (Queen Mary 2) are less into the party scene and more into the pretend-it's-1950 scene. (N.B.: Loved two crossings with them; this is not a minus.) They have a real ship's doctor and a real infirmary. Of course, that may be who you tried, but I think they'd be the best chance for a sailing.

Comment: Yes we talked with Cunard. I may be able to lie and say he's fit to travel and maybe have his specialist write a letter saying the same and just wait until he meets age requirement for Traveling with Cunard. Still haven't heard back from embassy.

Comment: Is this not a problem for your travel insurance company to solve, even if they have to buy a ship thereself!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cruise line are obviously concerned they may not have the expertise required in the event of an emergency and may incur liability for the health of your child.

There are usually ways round this - such as higher insurance cover etc., but in the first instance you should definitely speak to the embassy, yes - they may be able to offer guidance or a preferred option.